# jQuery change background color of table row

Tags: jquery

I have several tables. And I'm trying to add a class through jquery to all the rows of the table when i press link All. How can I do it without adding classes and id to the tables. Now class added to all the rows in each table when i click link "All" in any of the table. I have no idea how to select the table that owns the link "All".

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/21/) what i was trying.

```
$(function(){
   $('.table tbody input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
        $(this).closest('table tbody tr').toggleClass("np-tr-selected", this.checked);
    });
    $(".all").click(function(){
        $('table tbody tr').addClass("np-tr-selected");
    });
})
```

Comment: When you click All, did you also want the checkboxes to be checked, or just the background to change color?

Comment: the question was only about background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so like this:

```
$(".all").click(function(){
    $('tbody tr', $(this).closest('table')).addClass("np-tr-selected");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/24/

Answer (score 1):

You could use following snippet:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/22/)

```
$(function(){
   $('.table tbody input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass("np-tr-selected", this.checked);
    });
    $(".all").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('table').find('tbody tr').addClass("np-tr-selected").find(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You will add class to the table, not all the rows and the way to do it is by starting from $(this) then going up to .parent() as many times as your html requires, until you hit the table element.

```
 <table class="hitme">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="someclass" name="somename">
```

would require something like

```
  $('.somename').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().addClass('someotherclass');
  })
```

Comment: `$(this).closest('table')` is really better

Comment: Yes it is, didn't come to me at the time :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the color of the background and check the checkboxes when clicking All, use:

```
$(function(){
   $('.table tbody input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
        $(this).closest('table tbody tr').toggleClass("np-tr-selected", this.checked);
    });
    $(".all").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('table').find('tr:gt(0)').addClass("np-tr-selected").find('input').prop('checked', true);
    });
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Wy22s/23/)**

If you don't need to worry about the checkboxes, remove the `.find('input').prop('checked', true);`